# Disable minutes in bootstrap time picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-timepicker

I'm using bootstrap time picker

[image]

This is working, its script is like

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery('.timepicker').timepicker({
          format: 'LT',
          orientation: 'top',
          defaultTime: '',
      });
  </script>
```

i want to disable minutes so that users can only change hours.

Comment: You could *probably* just hide the time component using css.  If you could create a snippet and add the relevant script tags to create a time picker, it should be evident how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the minutes, set the `interval` to `60` so the loop goes like `10:00AM -> 11:00AM` and doesn't affect the minutes. `timeFormat` could be `hh:mmp` or `HH:mm` depending on your 12-hour or 24-hour requirement.